# Should my scholarship be tax-free?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, education

I am a grad student in the social sciences, and the vast majority of my tuition is waived, as long as I TA or RA at least half time during the year. I am also paid a stipend for my TA/RA work.

From what I've read, I believe that the tuition waiver should not count as taxable income, but I wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 5):

In general, yes, the tuition waiver itself is not taxable income.  Stipends or TA salaries, etc. will be taxable.  See [this IRS information](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p970/ch01.html#en_US_2013_publink1000177991) which says in part:

> A scholarship or fellowship is tax free (excludable from gross income) only if you are a candidate for a degree at an eligible educational institution.
> [...]
>
> Qualified education expenses.   For purposes of tax-free scholarships and fellowships, these are expenses for:
> Tuition and fees required to enroll at or attend an eligible educational institution
> [...]